# tar creates a duplicate within itself. using exec( )

Tags: exec, tar

Discovered this when creating a tar.gz file using php's exec(). I get a file within the unzipped version called 'p'. It can be uncompressed and contains the same files as the parent, but does not contain a copy of itself. Found that it also happens when running the same command from the command line.

Here is the command...

```
tar -czf /targetdir/backup.tar.gz *
```

I'm running this under OSX 10.8.2.

Comment: exec() shouldn't have any effect on this. this'd be purely a tar thing. check for oddities link symlinks pointing to/from other dirs within the same FS tree branch.

Comment: Thanks Marc B, sort of nailed it there. No actual symlinks, but it must have something to do with the fact that I was using the /Users/username/Pictures directory. I'm not sure what OSX is doing with that folder, but out side of that folder it functioned properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSX does something with the Pictures folder in the user's directory (and probably other 'special folders') that causes this issue. Thanks to Marc B for getting me to look at the folder again. Try the same command in a user created folder and it will work fine.